# Scanned documents only readable by the user that scanned ~linux

Tags: linux, chown, ownership

I've been troubleshooting some time for this, and I don't seem to be able to work out, what the solution could be.

I have a setup, where the copier is connected to my fileserver, so that when a user scans in a document, the scanned document comes into a folder on the fileserver that only that user can see.

Now the problem:
The problem is, that when the user has scanned in a document, and then moves it to another folder to share it with another user, the other user cannot see the file.
I've found that it's because of the ownership of the file is still set to the user that scanned it. It doesn't change, nomatter what folder it lands in.
I don't have a lot of experience in Linux, but I try to improve every day. Therefore, it might be a really simple solution, that I don't know of. But as I said, I have tried to troubleshoot, and search for solutions online.

Have anyone got an idea on how to deal with this problem? Maybe a workaround?

Thanks a lot in advance,
-Sebbeder

Comment: `the other user cannot see the file` - what do you mean this? Does `ls -Al <directory_where_the_file_is>` show it?

Comment: For example:
User1 scans a document, it lands in the User1-Scanner folder. User1 want User2 to see the file as well. So User1 moves the file to a folder, that both User1 and User2 has read/write access. However, User2 cannot see the file, until before I go into the file server and use the "chown" command for that file.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Depending on the UMASK set on your server, files of User1 will only be readable by User1.  He coud `chown` the file to make it accessible to a group both User1 and User2 are in.  Or he could `chown +r` it to make it readable by **everyone**.

Comment: permission sticks on moving but not copying. so if you are okey with multiple copies on same document, do copy instead of move

Comment: only works if copy destination is under umask 022 or more opening

Comment: A non-root user can't change the ownership of a file to another user.  They can change the group of a file to a group that they are a member of (and the other user can read it if they are also a member of that group and the file's perms allow group read).  Most relevantly for this question, they can change the permissions of a file to allow read and/or write access by group members or everyone.   e.g. `chmod g+r scanfile` would make it group-readable, and `chmod a+r scanfile` would make it readable by every user on the system.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I learned a lot :) 
The process for me will be to tell the users, that they need to copy instead of moving the files. The other solutions seems to require someone with root to go actively go and change the permissions of the files. Thanks again.

Comment: Any user can change the perms on their own files. Copying vs moving is not the answer, it's just something that **might** work around the problem **if** the user's `umask` is set to allow group or world read/write. Making sure the perms allow the other user to read and/or write the file is the answer.